# Make table cells with <a> clickable and respect tabbed browsing

Tags: javascript, html, browser, tabbed-browsing

Right now I'm doing a `td.click()` and then `window.location = td.find('a').attr('href')` but it doesn't work if I'm clicking to make a new tab.

And I can't programmatically click the `<a>`.

Any ideas?

Feel free to fork this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uDQPr/

Answer (score 0):

You could make the `<a>` fill up the entire cell. That way, you won't need any additional JavaScript to handle the click event. Adding `target="_blank"` to your `<a>` link will make it always open in a new tab (or a new window, for browsers that don't support tabs). Working example at http://jsfiddle.net/vTyAc/2/.

Here's the table code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://apple.com" target="_blank">Apple</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="http://youtube.com" target="_blank">YouTube</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And the CSS:

```
td {
    border: 1px solid;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```